# How can I get the actual generic parameter outside the generic class?

Tags: delphi, generics

Here is a stripped down snippet of a project of mine :

Interface part :

```
type
  TMainFormView<T:TCustomForm> = class(TInterfacedObject, IMainFormView)
  private
    ...
  protected
    function GetMainFormClass: TCustomFormClass;
    //
    property MainFormClass:TCustomFormClass read GetMainFormClass;
  public
    ...
  end;
```

Implementation part:

```
function TMainFormView<T>.GetMainFormClass: TCustomFormClass;
begin
  Result:= T;
end;
```

I've already refactored it and the former implementation was very ugly believe me (I used an inner class which I found out lately to be an overkill and not elegant).

Is there other better way to code it? My purpose is to be able to extract the "concrete" class of T and expose it through protected property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems a little vague but I understand it that you are asking for a slicker way to query an instance for the value of T, the type argument of the instantiated type. The only way I know to do this is via a method, exactly as you have done it. I think you already have the best solution.